# <Text> or @: not working in MVC4

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP MVC and as part of learning i was developing a small map appliation.

below is the code snippet

```
<ul>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    @foreach (var item in Model){
            @:AddLocationPin(@item.geo_lat, @item.geo_long, null, 'place 1'); 
           }
</script>
    </ul>
```

I expect the server to send to browse the  something like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AddLocationPin(1.5,-2.9, null, 'place 1'); 
AddLocationPin(11.5,-12.9, null, 'place 1');
 </script>
```

insted when I use Firebug on Firebfox I see the server sending the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

could anyone of your help me as to what I am doing wrong ? 
excuse me if this is a very basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once inside Razor block you don't need to put `@` at every line.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @foreach (var item in Model){
            AddLocationPin(@item.geo_lat, @item.geo_long, null, 'place 1');
           }
  </script>
```

Razor cheatsheet: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: looking into it further I am wondering if it is not even evaluating the @foreach because I tried to set some value in that loop and it dint mak it either.

Comment: accepting this as an answer as I think the issue is else where, I have posted another question for help on that.  Thanks Jakub

Comment: I think this is actually not a correct answer because the OP wanted javascript to be injected into the output (i.e. AddLocationPin is a javascript function that he wants to call).